# How did C++ change with the different editions of TC++PL?

Tags: c++

(In case you do not know, "TC++PL" stands for "The C++ Programming Language", a book written by the inventor of C++, Bjarne Stroustrup.)

I only have the third edition and was just wondering how C++ looked in the first and second editions. Obviously the third edition is the only one to cover ISO standard C++, but what are the major features that were added to C++ after the first edition was published and after the second edition was published?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let Bjarne Stroustrup explain in his own words: [A History of C++: 1979−1991](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/hopl2.pdf)

Answer (score 7):

Well, I only have the first and second editions... ;-)

First edition, 1986, didn't yet have exceptions. Iostreams were not templated. All that standard library stuff missing. 328 pages including index.

Second edition, 1991, had exceptions but not yet standard exception class hierarchy. Iostream still not templated. 699 pages including index.

Standardization in 1998 added *lots* of stuff. Including templatization of iostreams, standardization of exception hierarchy, wholesale inclusion of most of STL in standard library, etc. etc.

Cheers & hth.,

Comment: Did the first edition have templates at all? I remember flicking through a copy once and seeing some pretty horrible (by today's standards) generic macro code.

Comment: @Charles Bailey: 'flicking' or 'flipping' :)

Comment: @Charles: no, no templates in 1st ed. There is (was) a section on "generic list classes", that uses macros to sort of emulate generics. Quoting that: "Unfortunately, this can be quite painful when using the standard C preprocessor. The resulting macros are, however, quite easy to use". :-)